# I have a 500 point bounty that will expire soon. What happens to those points?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

I put a 500 point bounty on this question and think I was dumb about it:

[How do I get an ECDSA public key from just Bitcoin signature? … SEC1 4.1.6 key recovery for curves over (mod p)-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19665491/328397)

In almost a week, no answers, and no comments.  I don't even think there was a boost in visibility than if I did a much smaller bounty.

Perhaps the best thing I should have done is to boost it for several weeks with a 50 point bounty

My understanding is that the outcome will either be

- I lose the 500 points.  No benefit to the community, a huge rep loss for me.
- Someone posts a low quality answer that gets naively upvoted or via a puppet account...  The bounty is awarded to a poor answer that doesn't really help

My question is; what are my options if this were to occur?

Can I extend the duration of the bounty artificially?  Can I get a mod-level reissue of the rep, or an extension to this question?

I do think an answer to this question would benefit many C# developers interested in cryptography or Bitcoin, and think that whatever outcome results in a complete answer would be greatly beneficial for the community.

Comment: The bounty is like a ad. There are no garanties for answers and there is no refund.

Answer (score 4):

You've already lost the 500 points. That won't be refunded.

If you don't assign the bounty to an answer, one may be automatically assigned and will receive half of the bounty amount. (Highest-voted answer, minimum score 2, posted after bounty offered.)

If there's no qualifying answer, then the bounty is simply *gone*.